# Tubless rims with non tubeless tires -- what rim tape?

Tags: tire, tubeless, rim-tape

I run tubeless rims (specifically the new Mavic Open Pros) with the non-tubeless Continental GP GTs. The tires have lots of life left in them so I want to make the most of them in the meantime.

However recently I've been getting loads of punctures, and I think many of them are down the the rim strip not fully covering the whole rim bed (which is very wide). When I take the tire off I can see that some of the tape as been pushed right into the corner of the rim bed.

Should I just use tubeless rim tape with these rims & tires despite the fact I am not using a tubeless tire? It makes sense to me to use tubless rim tape as when these tires do wear out I probably will switch to tubeless.

Comment: When you say 'some of the tape as been pushed right into the corner of the rim bed' do you mean that the spokes and nipples are exposed? If that is happening you need different tape. It does not make sense to use tubeless tape with tubed tire if the tape isn't doing it's job properly.

Comment: No matter what rim tape you use it should match the width of the bed. There's also no reason not to use tubeless tape if the fitting is correct and the tape cannot slip sideways exposing holes, nipples and spokes.

Answer (score 2):

Tubeless tape is an acceptable substitute for any rim strip and, in many cases, will likely be an improvement over factory-installed rim strips. Just be certain to apply the correct width of tubeless tape (it should cover the entire width of the rim's interior from bead to bead) and prepare the rim's interior surfaces well by thoroughly cleaning/removing any residue from the previous rim strip adhesive, and any single threads from the beads if it was a cloth type of rim tape. Also ensure that the valve body hole is taped over first, then punctured only as much as is absolutely necessary to press the valve through as that helps with forming and retaining the airtight seal when switching to tubeless.